# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar(update) los value de los radio button de este formulario?

Tags: php, mysql

La BD (registro.sql):

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`cedula` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`usuario` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`login` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
`nivel` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Tengo el siguiente formulario: (busqueda.php)

```
            <form action="buscar.php" method="POST" name="frm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" for="cedula">Cédula:</label>

                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" name="cedula" id="cedula" type="text" value="" size="25" placeholder="Ingrese la cédula del usuario" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <input type= "submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info" name="btn2">
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

El cual consulta en la BD los datos(el # de id, nombre completo, login y el nivel del usuario, el cual puede ser: 1, 2 o 3) del id introducido, y los muestra en otro formulario: (buscar.php)

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");        
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$busqueda = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db1 WHERE cedula = $cedula");
while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($busqueda))
{   
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="desing.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    </br>
        <form  action="edit.php" method="POST" name="frm" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" for="cedula">Cédula:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4">

                <input class="form-control" name="cedula" id="cedula" type="text" value="<?php echo $cedula; ?>" size="25" placeholder="Ingrese la cédula del usuario" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" name="usuario" id="usuario" type="text" value="<?php echo $consulta['usuario']; ?>" size="40" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" for="login">Login:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <input class="form-control" id="login" type="text" value="<?php echo $consulta['login']; ?>" size="25" disabled>


                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2" for="nivel">Nivel:</label>
                <div class="radio col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="nivel" id="nivel" value="1" <?php echo $consulta['nivel']; ?> <?php if ($consulta['nivel'] == "1") echo 'checked="checked"' ?> name="nivel" >Nivel 1</label></br>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="nivel" id="nivel" value="2" <?php echo $consulta['nivel']; ?> <?php if ($consulta['nivel'] == "2") echo 'checked="checked"' ?> name="nivel" >Nivel 2</label></br>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="nivel" id="nivel" value="3" <?php echo $consulta['nivel']; ?> <?php if ($consulta['nivel'] == "3") echo 'checked="checked"' ?> name="nivel" >Nivel 3</label></br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-offset-4 col-sm-offset-5 col-md-offset-5">

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name="submit" value="Enviar">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  name="button" value="Regresar" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

En el formulario (buscar.php):

1. sólo se debe seleccionar el nivel deseado para el usuario consultado (nivel 1, nivel 2, nivel 3)
2. El resto de los datos del usuario se muestran en los inputs disabled.

Al presionar el botón enviar(submit) se debe actualizar el registro del nivel del usuario, por lo que en otro script php (edit.php) incluí lo siguiente:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
$nivel = $_POST['nivel'];
$cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE $tabla_db1 SET nivel='$nivel' WHERE 
cedula='$cedula'");
?>
```

Como resultado, me notifica el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: cedula in C:\xampp\htdocs\Modulo\edit.php on line 19
```

Tal como lo dice, no encuentra el valor de "cedula" ($cedula = $_POST['cedula'];) Que debe traer desde el input del formulario anterior.

Probé haciendo echo de los valor de "cedula" y "nivel", sólo me muestra el nivel que seleccioné, mas no la cédula. Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al poner el atributo "disabled" en el campo cedula lo haces "no utilizable como input", es decir, no pasa el valor. Para que tengas el valor manteniendo la funcionalidad puedes la cedula a través de input "type=hidden" o bien hacer que el input de la cédula sea "readonly" en lugar de deshabilitarlo.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por responder Carmen! Ahora sí funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Fenomenal, entonces marca la pregunta por favor como respondida para que no quede pendiente.